# A good place validation for business logic

Tags: database, validation, design-patterns, database-design, web-applications

OK, so let start from the beginning. For instance, I'm developing some big project. It isn't a secret for all of us that such projects contains a lot of common logic. Say, for example, that some online shop order must have some items and sum of prices of all items must be exactly 1000. So, I implement this logic in MVC3 web application and do validation on order. If there are issues it will tell user about issues and ask him to repost the form.

But project has another important part. It's DB. Here I can also wrap this validation logic in some stored procedure and add orders only through this proc to be sure that there is no inconsistencies. (Or should I use checks on table to be sure?)

Here's the stuck I run. It is necessary to dublicate logic in two places to get data integrity. Of course, I may store validation logic only on DB side. But I doubt it will decrease application performance.

I'm sure more experienced guys has a complete and elegant solution for this question.

So, how can I implement logic only in one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, not to everyone's liking

- Your database will outlast your client code
- You will have multiple client code bases for your database
- It's usual to have validation in several places: would you trust user input from a browser and skip server side validation?
- Define "validation": complex business rules or data integrity? If the latter, then it should be the RDBMS' responsbility

Edit, about the latter part

Not all logic needs to be implemented in the database: only logic that will be common to several client code bases. Or you can funnel these common requests through a separate tier/service that deals with it.

Note, some business logic is based on aggregations or cross-table or whole-table checks that simply are best done in the database

Comment: About fourth reason. I meant only that validation logic, that you cannot implements using RDBMS functionality like foreign keys, constraints and so on. So, indeed there is no way other than changing logic in two places when it changes?

Comment: @kseen: not in a practical way (I'm sure you could have SQL call a web service or such nonsense). However, I'll update

Comment: I know what to do with logic what simple lays on cross-table or aggregation checks. the topic of question is what to do with logic, that differs from mentioned above. So, for example is there any way to check that sum of order items' prices are equal to 1000?

Comment: @kseen: that is an SUM().. HAVING query in the database. Ideas: if this limit is variable, you could pass in the 1000 from the client code which does know about it. Or store it in the database for several clients to read

Comment: Good points made here but the sad fact is that SQL is almost useless for implementing anything other than extremely simple business rules. Even simple inclusion dependency and join dependency data integrity constraints are something that most SQL DBMSs cannot manage to do. Most business rules are usually best implemented in a middle tier as an independent service layer that can be shared between applications - possibly using a dedicated rules engine product or data integration / data quality tool.

Comment: @dportas: agree. Use the best tool/architecture for the job. I was trying to highlight the fact the boundaries are blurred in some cases that are best done in SQL. I've seen too many DBs with no FKs, no uniqueness constraints, poor concurrency etc because of "we can do it all in the ORM" mentality. And likewise, some real shit that should have never been in a database at all.